# What components do I need to display an analog DC current value on a 7-segment display array?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, 7segmentdisplay

(See edit below)

**Original Question:**

This is the first PCB I've ever tried to build and I need a little help getting pointed in the right direction.  I've spent hours researching things and I think I'm finally to the point where I can ask an intelligent question.

I need something that senses current and does two things:

1. Outputs a 0-5V signal (proportional to the current) that gets sent to an external data logger.
2. Displays the current on a 3-digit 7-segment display.

This will be used in an automotive setting, so we're talking about 12-16V DC with up to a 30A continuous load that needs to be measured and logged.

I am looking at a Hall effect sensor such as the Allegro [ACS770LCB-100B-PFF-T](https://www.digikey.com/short/z4tpwt) but I don't know how to display the current on the 7-segment array.  Do I need an ADC, microcontroller, both, or neither?  Is that Allegro sensor the right thing to be looking at?

Any suggestions on which types of components (with model numbers if possible) I should be looking at will help greatly.

**Edited to narrow focus of the question:**

How do I transform a 0-5V signal into something that a [PIC Microcontroller can display on a 7-Segment display array](https://microcontrollerslab.com/7-segment-display-interfacing-with-pic-microcontroller/)?

Comment: So I could suggest some circuits to help, but I'm willing to bet you can find something on amazon for 10$ that does exactly this.

Comment: [Shopping questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and what happens to them.

Comment: The article you linked to refers to the [PIC18F4550.](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632e.pdf)  The datasheet says it has a 10 bit analog to digital converter.  That's probably adequate for what you want.

Comment: It's probably easier to use an Arduino, though.

Comment: I hate it when I ask questions where the answer is RTFM, but I guess I'm guilty in this case.  I will accept it as the answer if you post it as such.  Meanwhile I'm off to learn about MPLAB and PIC controllers!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not familiar with electronics or with writing software, probably it's better (and certainly easier) to source a pre-made *panel meter* that measures voltage. These are available from the usual places - Mouser, Digi-Key, etc. It includes the ADC and converts a voltage input to a readout.

Here's an example of a voltage-input panel meter: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/Murata_05032019_dms01-vp-rs12-c_3-20-19-1591455.pdf

The Hall sensor can be connected directly to this meter, which can be set up for the gain required (span) to get the appropriate amperage readout.

There are also Arduino projects that integrate a display and use the chip’s ADC to read a voltage from a current sensor and display it. Here’s an example: https://www.electronicshub.org/interfacing-acs712-current-sensor-with-arduino/